# Use animated GIF in desktop application

Tags: java, image, swing, gif

I was just wondering how to use animated GIFs in my program (right now I'm just using PNGs). I just want to be able to cycle through the different pictures in the GIFs, but I don't know the classes to use.

What classes are used to load and display animated GIFs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
new JLabel( new ImageIcon( URL ) );
```

### E.G.

[image: ShowAnimatedGif]  [image: Star Zoom]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.URL;

class ShowAnimatedGif {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final URL url = new URL("http://pscode.org/media/starzoom-thumb.gif");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(url));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I in-lined the animated GIF just in case my pscode.org site ever disappears.  The direct link to the version embedded at SO (edit the URL in the source) is http://i.stack.imgur.com/4zxj9.gif

Comment: [I'm re_posted your nice idea](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/416639/1777566#post1777566)