# Adding images on Java JFrame - Netbeans

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, jframe

I'm using **NetBeans 7.1** to code in Java. I have already created a `JFrame` filled with some `labels, textbox and buttons`. How can I do to import some image `(JPG,PNG,etc...)` from my PC into the same `JFrame`? On an specific location of the frame.

Comment: Did you create the code by hand or via the form editor? You may also want to take a look at [How to use labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: *"How can I do to import some image (JPG,PNG,etc...) from my PC into the same JFrame?"*  Did you miss the 3 posts about using images in desktop apps that were posted earlier ***today***?  Please search on these things first!  E.G. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8958814/418556), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14037856/418556) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5752471/418556)..

Comment: @MadProgrammer Via form editor

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use animated GIF in desktop application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958808/use-animated-gif-in-desktop-application)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72159010/problem-using-icon-in-java-swing-netbeans could you assist me in resolving t issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open the form in NetBeans form editor.
2. Add a `JLabel` from the pallete to the form
3. Select the label you just added and click the "..." button next to the `icon` property
4. Fill out the properties.

It's normally best that the images reside within the project folder, makes deployment easier in the long run.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! So easy. I'm new to Java JFrames as you can see. Thanks again!

Comment: actully havnt seeing any icon property? any help?

Comment: @AlitheDev 1. Make sure you're using a `JLabel`; 2. Make sure it's selected. See the added screen shoot

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you add the JLabel to use it from Swing Controls not AWT.

Comment: Perhaps add an example of the import statement for this answer?

Comment: There are two types of controls which you can use Label from: Swing Controls and AWT. Make sure you choose the Label under category Swing Control. To remove any confusion, make sure that your Label is initiated as 'new javax.swing.JLabel();' not 'new java.awt.Label();'

Comment: Hats off to this answer, solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy Image to your Netbeans project.
2. Add new label to the frame.
3. Select the label and Right click->Go to Properties.
4. In Icon property select image by down arrow as shown in image.

[image]