# Problem Using icon in Java Swing, Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-8

[Icon - image within project Got errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ3dM.png)

[Icon - external image (file path) No errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sfDH.png)

I'm trying to set the icon image using the image within project method, but it keep got exception error. How to solve the exception error shown in Figure 1 ?
Because when i opened the project in another pc, all the icons were dissappeared.

Error code generated

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:234)
at com.mycompany.javaassignment.NewJFrame.initComponents(NewJFrame.java:36)
at com.mycompany.javaassignment.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:19)
at com.mycompany.javaassignment.NewJFrame$1.run(NewJFrame.java:96)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Dont post screenshots with the error message, please post the Stacktrace. Show the lines of code which cause the problem. What have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to set the icon image using the image within project method, but it keep got exception error. However, when I using the external image method, it works tho. But the cons of using external image is when the project is open in another pc, all the icons disappeared. @MoritzSchmidt

Comment: The answer to this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/loading-resources-like-images-while-running-project-distributed-as-jar-archive) should help.